# What are the benefits of initializing variables in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, initialization

I understand that it's not necessary to initialize variables, but what are the benefits of doing so?  It doesn't effect the scope of the variable nor the data type.  The only reasons I could find were:

- Avoid resulting in "undefined"
- Explicitly show what the variable is intended for i.e. `let myArray = [];`

Comment: Sometimes you just want to for code clarity. Sometimes it helps if you want to initialize it to different values depending on other criteria; eg `let x; if (y) { x = 1} else {x = 2}`

Comment: Given your 2 reasons, I don't know why you wouldn't initialise your variables.

Comment: go to JavaScript tutorial  there you will get your question's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you define the variable does actually affect the scope of the variable.

There is a big difference between these statements as far as scope, and also as far as mutability for `const`:

```
x = 1;
var x = 1;
let x = 1;
const x = 1;
```

For instance, the first line will create a global variable, the second will create a function scoped variable, and the third line will create a block scoped variable.

Another difference is the concept of "hoisting". `let` and `const` do not "hoist".

Answer (score 0):

Initializing variables provides an idea of the intended use (and intended data type).

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_best_practices.asp

Comment: This shows the reason I've already mentioned: "provides an idea of the intended use"